# Converting strings in a dataframe column to an index value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using Python and Pandas, I have a

1. dataframe, df
2. with a column entitled 'letters'
3. a list, letlist = ['a','b','c','d']

I would like to create a new column, 'letters_index', where the generate value would be the index of the string in column letters, in the list letlist

I tried

```
df['letters_index'] = letlist.index(df['letters'])
```

However, this didn't work. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, You need:

```
letlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
letters
0   a
1   b
2   b
3   d
4   c
```

And then

```
df['new_col'] = df['letters'].apply(lambda x: letlist.index(x))
```

Output:

```
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    3
4    2
Name: letters, dtype: int64
```

Beware that if the value in the column is not present in the list it would throw a `ValueError`.

Comment: This works great! is there anyway that we can add the output as a new column in the dataframe?